# User-Defined Table Type insertion sometimes causing conversion error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-types

I have a User-Defined Table Type called **tvpInsertedColumns**:

```
CREATE TYPE [Audit].[tvpInsertedColumns] AS TABLE(
    [ColumnName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [NewValue] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

In a Stored Procedure I am attempting to do this *(Both @Name and @Phone are VARCHARs)*:

```
DECLARE @AuditColumns Audit.tvpInsertedColumns
INSERT INTO @AuditColumns (ColumnName,NewValue)
    SELECT  'Name',@Name UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Phone',@Phone
```

This fails with the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the
>   varchar value 'Some Name'
>   to data type int.

However, in another Stored Procedure I am doing this *(@AddressLine1 and @AddressLine1 are VARCHARs)*:

```
DECLARE @AuditColumns AS Audit.tvpInsertedColumns
INSERT INTO @AuditColumns (ColumnName,NewValue)
    SELECT  'AddressLine1',@AddressLine1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  'AddressLine2',@AddressLine2
```

And everything works just fine.

Both Stored Procedures are just doing a simple insert and then trying to use the type along with another stored procedure that takes the UDT as a parameter.

This is my first real experience with UDTs, so I hope I'm just missing something obvious, but this makes no sense to me. Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
DECLARE @AuditColumns Audit.tvpInsertedColumns
INSERT INTO @AuditColumns (ColumnName,NewValue)
SELECT  'Name',@Name UNION ALL
SELECT  'Phone',@Phone
```

I don't know much about UDTs but what I think is happening is that,
at one point, either `@name` or `@phone` values are of type integer.

Try to cast @Name and @Phone to varchar

```
INSERT INTO @AuditColumns (ColumnName,NewValue)
SELECT  'Name', cast(@Name as varchar) UNION ALL
SELECT  'Phone', cast(@Phone as varchar)
```

Comment: +1 and FYI, it isn't a UDT error but datatype precedence in the UNION ALL before the INSERT happens

Comment: This wasn't quite right, but it got me to the solution (and that's all I wanted).  The `@Name` and `@Phone` variables never changed types, the problem was that at some point (After my sample cutoff) I was also inserting an integer assuming that there would be an automatic conversion.  Casting all non `VARCHAR` types to `VARCHAR(MAX)` fixed the issue. I suspect gbn is correct that this has nothing to do with the UDTs but rather with datatype precedence in `UNION` statements. Thank you both for your help.